# Thread safe concurrent queues C example in Windows without Pthread

Tags: c, windows, queue

I could not find a thread safe queue implementation in C for Windows which does not use pthread. I don't want to use pthreads. Are there any other alternatives?

Can someone please explain a C program how to ensure that the queue enque deque can be synchronized on Windows?

Comment: You can look here for Windows-specific ways of thread synchronization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-synchronization

Comment: Both `cygwin` and `mingw` support `pthreads`. You could use those. Or, you could pull their source and see how they implement pthreads on top of native win32 API calls. Or, a web search of `win32 threads` will produce a lot of links to MS docs

Comment: Create a critical section, condvar or a semaphore.  The Windows API provides plenty of synchro objects that you can use to protect a container:)